# Having issues with fwrite and fgets processing it

Tags: c

```
 char string[50], s[50];
 File *f = tmpfile();
 count = 1;

 while (fgets(string, 50, stdin)) {
    if (string[0] == '!') {
        rewind(f);
    } else {
        fwrite(string, 50, 1, f);
    }

    if (strcmp("history\n", string) == 0) {
        rewind(f);
        while(fgets(s, 50, f)) {
            printf("\t%d  %s", count, s);
            count++;
        }
        count = 1;
    }
 }
```

The context of this code is not hugely important. The problem is that let's say `fgets` takes in "ls", "date", and "history". The resulting output is:

```
1  ls
2   3  te
4   5  ory
6
```

It should be:

```
1  ls
2  date
3  history
```

Comment: Looks like you get some `'\r'`s in your buffer. And you should probably only `fwrite` `strlen(string)` bytes.

Comment: @DanielFischer I know the question is a year and a half old, but do you want to pull that out into an answer?

Answer (score 0):

*Since feature requests to [mark a comment as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82099/answering-comment-answered-questions) remain declined, I copy the above solution here.*

Looks like you get some '\r's in your buffer. And you should probably only fwrite strlen(string) bytes. –  Daniel Fischer